# Error write to file batch_x.tmp

Tags: magento-1.8, importexport

I am trying to import products from a csv file which i exported last time, located in var/export folder.
after configuring the import profiler when i click the "Run Profile in Popup" i get immediately this error.

```
* Starting Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Parser_Csv :: parse 
* Error write to file batch_4.tmp 
* Finished profile execution.
```

any suggestions, i am sure this is not related to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i figured to get rid of the above issue, is to **save the settings after any changes** and then run the import profile. in my case the previous setting was to Interactive and i was using local/remote server for data transfer and i guess it was not able to locate the file.

hope this saves time for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Magentos import and export format is sadly not the same, therefore you can't import what you exported :-(

Comment: thanks for a quick reply, however, i resolved the issue.

Comment: Please tell us how!

Comment: i was altering the settings of import and was trying to import at the same time, after few tries, i saved the profile and gave it another try and it worked